# How to build custom WordPress gallery?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm new to WordPress and i want to know 
how can i build gallery like this in WordPress

http://rafalmilach.com/black-sea-of-concrete/

If anybody know please help me fast !
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

> NextGEN Gallery is a full integrated Image Gallery plugin for
>   WordPress with a slideshow option. Before I started writing the plugin
>   I studied all the existing image and gallery plugins for WordPress.
>   Some of them are really good and well designed, but the gap I filled
>   was a simple administration system at the back end which can also
>   handle multiple galleries

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: I know this plugin but can i build gallery same like http://rafalmilach.com/black-sea-of-concrete/ gallery using this plugin

Comment: Definitely - have you checked out the demo? It offers a lot of customizable actions: atermark function : You can add a watermark image or text
JavaScript Effect : Use any available popular image effect : Shutter, Thickbox, Lightbox or Highslide
Multiple CSS Stylesheet : Use a nice shadow effect for your thumbnails with your own CSS file
Slideshow : Full integrated slideshow as jQuery or Flash solution
TinyMCE : Button integration for easy adding the gallery tags
Sidebar Widget : Show a slideshow, random or recent picture at your sidebar